# Why isn't my usb ubuntu boot working on my Asus k53e laptop

Tags: usb-drive

I currently have windows7 and want to be able to dual boot on my laptop. I followed the directions given to make a dual boot flash drive and it worked on my desktop computer, but when I try to use it with my laptop (asus k53e) it says boot error. I have my flash drive set as the top priority bios to boot from, but every time I boot it it says boot error. I had the flash drive formatted, so the only files running on it are the ones installed in the process given to make a bootable usb device

Comment: Is boot error the only thing it says, or is there more to it?

Comment: Just "boot error" and then it runs my wWindows boot

Comment: And what does the screen look like when it says this? Also, are you sure that the ISO you downloaded and flashed to the USB stick wasn't corrupted during the download? You can check via [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). What size is the USB stick? And, finally, what method did you use to create the USB stick?

Comment: Black screen. I am not, but it ran well on my desktop and I was able to run Windows side by side ubuntu. I will check that. I used pendrive linux's universal installer

Comment: Okay. Check the MD5 sum of the ISO and if it does match, then try using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create the bootable stick.

Comment: MD5 sum matched. I reformatted my usb and tried using unetbootin from the iso file and now when I try to boot from it it says remove all other media devices or cds, press any key to restart

Comment: That's strange. Have you tried using putting the ISO on a DVD and booting from that? Your computer *should* allow you to boot from USB, but it never hurts to try a different media.

Comment: Do you have access to any other computer where you could boot from the USB stick as a test (without installing anything)?

Comment: I will try to make a DVD of it next.

Comment: @CalebRichter: Indeed, make a DVD or upgrade your firmware.  You seem to be able to have UEFI and that's different from BIOS and some UEFI hardware doesn't seem to like USB boot.  Please report back whether or not DVD boot works fine.

Comment: I tried various methods to USB boot my K53E without success. Then I tried it with the HARD DRIVE REMOVED and it booted fine. (The reason I had the HD removed was, I wanted to do a fsck on it from a USB booted system, so I moved the drive to another computer which did boot from USB.)